# Sum of referenced ranges in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google spreadsheets, how do I find the sum of two ranges referenced from different spreadsheets

I want to use something like

```
=(IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet1","A1:A100")+ IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet2","A1:A100"))
```

and get the sum

Apparently, the above doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer:

Arrayformula is what I was looking for. It basically applies the formula treating the range as a range, instead of as a single element. I still donot totally understand why this works. would be really happy if someone could explain this

I just used

```
ARRAYFORMULA((IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet1","A1:A100")+IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet2","A1:A100")))
```

and suddenly everything works as it should.

Shouldn't the + operator be conscious of the input type it is getting and automatically respond by returning the appropriate type? why do I need to explicitly specify that this is an array formula

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue yesterday. Solution was:

```
=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet1","SheetName!A1:A100")) + SUM(IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet2","SheetName!A1:A100"))
```

No need to use `ARRAYFORMULA()`

2 important notes.

1. You will probably see a `#REF!` error in your cell with a red color in the corner. You'll need to hover over it and allow access to the spreadsheets that you're referencing.
2. If any of the original data in the spreadsheet ranges you're referencing in `A1:A100` contain errors such as

```
#NULL!
#DIV/0!
#VALUE!
#REF!
#NAME?
#NUM!
#N/A
```

then your formula must be modified to include `SUMIF()` as follows

```
=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet1","SheetName!A1:A100"), ">0") + SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("keyofsheet2","SheetName!A1:A100"), ">0")
```

This ensures that it's only adding anumbers and not error codes.